# How to extend from a class present in the scope of a system verilog interface?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I was going through this since some of my UVC use this methodology:

https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/uvm/easier_uvm_guidelines/parameterized_interface/

But i want to extend the class in the interface and add/override some more functionality.

But when i tried to override the class, the compiler could not find the class, since it is scoped in the interface.

Any suggestions as to how I can override the class instead of re-implementing all the functions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is one problem with using this methodology - you can only extend the class from within the interface. But that is no different from using a virtual interface — you cannot extend the interface.

The best thing you could do in put the extended class inside the interface. Use the factory to override the construction of the class.